# Sample app created with Angular8 not rendering in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular8

I have created sample app with Angular 8, it works with Edge and Chrome but renders nothing in case of IE11

1. Updated "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json
2. Uncommented below lines in polyfill.ts and installed both packages..

import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';

Getting below error in console for vendor.js

SCRIPT1046: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: I think that's because you use duplicate properties. There're similar threads, such as  [add both styleUrls and styles to one component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528605/angular-2-multiple-definitions-of-a-property-not-allowed-in-strict-mode-in-ie1), [set the same class for different evaluations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505897/multiple-definitions-of-a-property-not-allowed-in-strict-mode-angular) and so on. There's also [an article](https://www.dev6.com/Multiple-Definitions-of-a-Property-Not-Allowed-in-Strict-Mode) you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you @YuZhou for your response. I am trying to run app generated by cli in IE11. I didn't update any code apart from tsconfig.json and polyfills.ts which is based on some of the articles about this issue.

Comment: I created a sample app with Angular8 and modified it according to [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455). Then it can runs well in IE11. You can try the ways provided in it.

Comment: I have followed all the steps but still getting the same error (SCRIPT1046) in console. I am using NodeJs v10.14.2 is that a problem?

Comment: I'm using NodeJs v10.15.3. I think this shouldn't be a problem. I have met the situation that I followed all the steps but didn't work in the end. Finally I delete the app and create it again according to the steps then it works...

Comment: @YuZhou thanks. I created another app and it started working but then was wondering why it did not work earlier; so verified differences between both apps and found out  Ivy was enabled in tsconfig.app.json  like this "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  } after disabling this option it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow any one option mentioned from [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455) and make sure you have not enabled Ivy compiler in tsconfig.app.json

"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }